# Cannot find created database from AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbQSs-_d-yM&list=LLGMGlkdnRaYJ18SFspK9fOQ&index=2) tutorial to install a Wordpress website on an Amazon EC2 instance successfully.

After creating an EC2 instance and opening your terminal, the tutorial explains the following steps:

Login by your elastic ip:

```
ssh ec2-user@elastic-ip -i pem-location
```

Update server:

```
sudo yum update
```

Switch to super user:

```
sudo su
```

Install Apache webserver:

```
yum install httpd
```

Start Apache server:

```
service httpd start
```

Install PHP mysql:

```
yum install php php-mysql
```

Install mysql:

```
yum install mysql-server
```

Start mysql service:

```
service mysqld start
```

Create database:

```
mysqladmin -uroot create DATABASE-NAME
```

Setup and secure database:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

After finishing the above steps, you download and install Wordpress in /var/www/html

The problem is that I now have a running Wordpress website including database, but I cannot find a database in my Amazon management console. Also not under my Database->RDC instances. So where is this created database and where/how can I find it? Or should I setup this another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed MySQL on your EC2 instance, not created an RDS instance.  You would not be able to "see" this database through any sort of AWS console or CLI actions.

If you truly want your database to be on RDS (which I would actually recommend rather than running on EC2 if the extra cost is not a consideration), you need to create the RDS instance separately and set it up to accept whatever EC2 security group you are using for your instance.

You have NO command line access to RDS, so there is no way to do something like `yum install mysql-server` to create an RDS, however you can use the AWS command line tools to instantiate an RDS instance if you need to be able to script the instantiation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This helps me understanding it more. So I am gonna try to create a RDS in my management console (script the instantiation is not necessary), and then I only need to connect in my database config file right?

Comment: @Robbert That is correct, you will need to configure your RDS endpoint in your application config.  You will also need to apply your EC2 security group to the RDS instance so the EC2 instance(s) can talk to the RDS instance.  If you want to use any sort of DB admin tool (MySQL Workbench, etc.) you will also need to either access via SSH tunnel into your EC2 instance, or add another entry in RDS security config to allow direct access (not recommended unless you have static IP from which to access the RDS and can open access only to that IP).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly, but to give some information, the INSTANCE means just a computer. So, you can't find your DB on RDC instances because it's on EC2 INSTANCE. And, the database is INSTALLED on EC2 machine, so the Amazon don't have to find and manage the mysql server, because it is bothersome from the supplier's point of view.

So, after the ssh login, just command mysql on the console. Then, maybe terminal moves into mysql server, and then the console shape changes from $ to mysql> . To use your database properly, you have to know the sql query grammer exactly. But I believe you're not very good at dealing with database, so why don't you use the phpmysqladmin? Maybe

```
yum install phpmysqladmin
```

After installing it, you can manage database on GUI mode(on the website). Search the 'phpmysqladmin' at google, and install it, and then study about mysql grammar!

I hope this might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this explains a lot! I am gonna try to install the phpmyadmin, but maybe I am gonna try it with a RDS as well. I am a beginner in this world, so your answer helps me to learn it step by step.

Comment: @Robbert Thanks for your compliment. But I'm little bit curious about why you are using AWS since AWS isn't free(not regarding free tier). You can test with your own computer without payment. So, if you have some interest not to pay for AWS, search "virtual machine", "virtualbox", "vmware" on google. When I'm studing, I used to use local virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for thinking. I will watch your suggestions, but I am trying to move our websites from our current hosting service to AWS. So I need to learn and work with it to understand it.